# Setting background color to all the activities and fragment by style

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to set the background color for all my entire app and I could not do it. WHat I am doing is this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme"> <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/holo_gray</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/holo_gray</item>
</style>
```

I also tried with:

```
<item name="android:background">@color/holo_gray</item>
```

I want to have the same default background color of Api 14 in lower APIs, that light gray.

I know that I could fix it by adding a android:background="@color/holo_gray" in every root layout but I want to do it by style, to avoid repeat this line in all my xml layout.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Doesn't windowBackground set the color for getWindow.getDecorView()?

Comment: Do not test that, but i am doing something wrong??

Comment: Are you setting the app theme within your manifest or code?

Comment: Are you making the change in all the styles folders under values-14 (values-11, values, etc)?

Comment: I only made the change in values, just want to do it for Android 2.2 and 2.3 because I am trying to use the same background color as Holo for the default background.

Comment: wdziemia I already do that, it is in my manifest in the application tag.

Answer (score 0):

holo_gray is not work in lower version so you should write you own color instead of it.Making the change in all value folder styles 
    
    @color/"holo_gray"(Replace your own color)

Comment: holo_gray is my own color defined in my colors.xml file =D

Comment: Then making the change in all value folder styles

Answer (score 0):

If you have ListViews in your layouts, they possess a default white background on 2.2. Try setting android:background="@null" on them, so your window background can show up.